# How to point an ember app to Staging environment VS Production environment upon deploying a test link?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am having a problem when it comes to directing a test link to `staging` environment VS to `production` environment.

Current behaviour: When I tried to run this command on my terminal `ember deploy staging` and it created a test link successfully. However, my component has a line of code that checks which environment the app currently pointed to. Unfortunately, it pointed to `production` environment

Expected behaviour: What I am trying to achieve is when I run the command `ember deploy staging` it should point to `staging` environment not `production` environment

Question: **How to tell ember that create a test linkfor a staging environment?**

Please see my code below for `../config/deploy.js`

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(deployTarget) {
  var ENV = {
    build: {
      environment: 'production'
    },
  };

  ENV['revision-data'] = {
    type: 'git-commit'
  };

  ENV['s3'] = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
    bucket: 'sample',
    prefix: deployTarget + '/dist/www',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    filePattern: '**/*.{js,css,png,gif,ico,jpg,xml,txt,svg,swf,eot,ttf,woff,woff2}'
  };

  ENV['redis'] = {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    maxRecentUploads: 30
  };

  ENV['gzip'] = {
    'filePattern': '**/*.{js,css,json,ico,xml,txt,svg,eot,ttf,woff,woff2}'
  };

  ENV['rollbar'] = {
    accessToken: process.env.ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    accessServerToken: process.env.ROLLBAR_SERVER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    minifiedPrependUrl: 'https://cdn1-' + deployTarget + '.sample.com/dist/www/',
    rollbarConfig: {
      enabled: true,
      environment: deployTarget,
      captureUncaught: true
    }
  };

  if (deployTarget === 'production') {
    ENV.rollbar.minifiedPrependUrl = 'https://cdn1.sample.com/dist/www/';
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

this is the code of my component that checks which environment you are currently in once you created a test link `/components/my-component/component.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  isProduction: config.environment === 'production',
  myEnvironment: config.environment;
});
```

And the `myEnvironment` returns `production` environment upon logging `{{log myEnvironment}}` on my `/component/my-component/template.hbs`

This is the code of my `.env.deploy.staging`

```
CLIENT_HOST=https://staging.sample.com
ASSETS_PREFIX=https://cdn1-staging.sample.com/dist/www/
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCDEF123456
S3_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=ABCDEF123456

ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN=ABCDEF123456
ROLLBAR_SERVER_ACCESS_TOKEN=ABCDEF123456
```

Any response is much appreciated. Hoping someone could help me, thank you!